# Can't resolve the load error for telegram bot

Tags: ruby, telegram-bot

i've followed https://www.process.st/telegram-bot/ steps for creating a telegram bot. an absolute beginner to coding and i can't seem to get my bot to respond at all even after renaming the file.

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from bot.rb:1:in `<main>'
    1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- telegramtest_bot (LoadError)```
````

Comment: Welcome to SO. When you post a question about an error, it is important to also provide enough code (preferably a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or a snippet of your code that will help us help you. In your case the error trace indicates the problem is in ``bot.rb`` (line 1), so providing at least the relevant parts of that file would help. Having said that, the error also indicates that you are trying to require ``telegramtest_bot``. Are you sure that's right? Check the tutorial and compare what it says to require.

Answer (score 0):

Looking over the tutorial, it looks like the gem is "telegram_bot" and not "telegramtest_bot". Gem requirees are exact wording.

e.g. require "nokogiri"

Additionally, you can version the gem in your gemfile.

This post seems to be a good overview of how "require" works: https://www.educba.com/ruby-require/

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following in order to resolve it (for windows users):

1. Navigate to your telegram bot folder
2. Install bundle
3. run ruby bot.rb

Worked for me when i did that! [image]